# Django modelformset creates new record instead of updating existing one

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a System that can have one or more Models. I have modeled this relationship in the database with a manytomany field. The code below is for editing the system and its associated methods in a single form.

Adding a *new* method by filling out its form and pressing submit works *only the first time*. If I then make a small change and submit again, I get the following message (generated by the code below):

```
METHODFORMSET.ERRORS: [{}, {'name': [u'Method with this Name already exists.']}]
```

This is caused by the fact that the name field is unique, but it should have *updated*, not *created* a new record, even though I am using the POST data to generate the methodformset instance...

Note that this behaviour only applies to the last appended method instance, not to ones that were already present in the table.

Here is the relevant code, can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
def sysedit(request, sys_id):

    system = System.objects.get(id=sys_id)
    MethodFormSet = modelformset_factory(Method, form=MethodForm)

    post = None
    if request.POST:
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if 'add_method' in request.POST:
            post['method-TOTAL_FORMS'] = repr(int(
                                                post['method-TOTAL_FORMS'])+ 1)

    systemform = SystemForm(data=post, instance=system)

    methodformset = MethodFormSet(data=post, prefix='method',
            queryset=Method.objects.filter(id__in=system.method.all()))

    if methodformset.is_valid():
        mfs = methodformset.save()
        print 'SAVED-method', mfs
        for mf in mfs:
            if systemform.is_valid():
                sp = systemform.save(mf)
                print 'SYSTEM', sp
            else:
                print 'SYSFORMSET.ERRORS:', systemform.errors
    else:
        print 'METHODFORMSET.ERRORS:', methodformset.errors

    return render_to_response('sysedit.html', 
            {'systemform': systemform, 
            'methodformset': methodformset, 
            'system': system},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))


class System(models.Model):
    method = models.ManyToManyField(Method)
    ...

class Method(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)
    ...

class MethodForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Method

class SystemForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, new_method=None, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        m = super(SystemForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
        if new_method:
            m.method.add(new_method)
        if commit:
            m.save()
        return m

    class Meta:
        model = System
        exclude = ('method')
```

[**EDIT after Sergzach's answer**]:

The problem is not how to deal with the `Method with this name already exists` error, but to prevent that from occurring in the first place. I think the actual problem may have something to do with the way modelformsets deal with new forms. Somehow it looks like it always tries to create a new instance for the last formset, regardless of whether it already exits.

So if I do not add a new formset after the last one was appended, the modelformset will try to re-create the last one (even though it was just created on the previous submit).

The initial situation is that I have 1 valid Method instance and 1 new unbound instance in the methodformset. I then fill out the form and hit save, which validates both Methods and binds the 2nd one, which is then saved to the table.
So far all is well, but if I then hit save the 2nd time the error occurs. Maybe this has to do with the fact that method-TOTAL_FORMS=2 and method-INITIAL_FORMS=1. Could it be that this causes modelformset to force a create on the 2nd Method?

Can anyone confirm/deny this?

[**Edit after a weekend of not looking at the code**]:

The problem is caused by the fact that I am saving the forms in the view and after saving, I am sending the original methodformset instance (from **before** the save) to the template. The problem can be solved by re-instantiating modelformset **after** the save, using the queryset and NOT the POST data.

So the general rule to prevent errors like this, is either to go to a different page after a save (avoid it altogether), or use the above solution.

Before I post this as THE solution, I need to do more testing.

Comment: OK, I see my answer was not about your problem. I will review it.

Comment: The principle is similar and more complicated code is required because we have a deal with a modelformsets but not with forms.

Comment: I have changed my answer. Please view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by re-instantiating modelformset after the save (see edit at the bottom of the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate each form when saving a formset. I have created a simple example (similar to your code) and it works well for me. It creates new objects if there is no object with a such name otherwise it edits an existing object.

You need a form to edit your model objects:

```
class EditMethodForm( forms.ModelForm ):
   class Meta:
      model = Method
      exclude = ( 'name', )
```

Then instead of methodformset.is_valid() you do the next:

```
for methodform in methodformset:
    try:
        instance = Method.objects.get( name = request.POST[ 'name' ] )
    except Method.DoesNotExist:
        methodform.save()
    else:
        editmethodform = EditMethodForm( request.POST, instance = instance )
        if editmethodform.is_valid():
            editmethodform.save()
```

There are some additional features in your code. I show the working principle. Is it enough to understand the solution?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer. I don't think the uniqueness of **method**.name (not system.name) is the problem, it just makes the actual problem visible by producing the `Method with this Name already exists` error when the **method** formset is validated. The real problem is that somehow my code wants to create a new instance of Method every time instead of updating the existing one.

Comment: Thank you for the new solution. If I understand it correctly, you are catching the `Method with this Name already exists` error and providing a workaround for it. I can apply this as a last resort solution, but it appears to me that there is a  more fundamental problem with the code, because the `Method with this Name already exists` error should not occur in the first place.

Comment: @JohnPeters I have changed my answer to a solution without a checking the 'name' key. Is it clear enough now?

Comment: @JohnPeters I think these limitations is related to the situation we have Django models and a real SQL database which does not know about the last ones. Django models (without initialization) don't contain  information about a current state of a database. To select all rows every time we want to change a row is a too expensive operation